# What API permissions do I need to change status of commits in pull requests

Tags: api, github

What API permissions do I need to change status of commits in pull requests received from users?

Currently I'm using `repo:status` - but that gives me access to commit status only on my own repos.  I'm building a ci service - like travis, circleci. Not sure, how they can change status in pull requests

Comment: You might look at the documentation for the jenkins plugin that does this, it would need the same permissions added

Comment: What do you mean by *changing the status of commits*?

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/

Answer (score 1):

`repo` permission is needed.

> **repo**  - Grants read/write access to code, commit statuses, collaborators, and deployment statuses for public and private repositories and organizations.

https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes